# Send SMS in background on Swift

Tags: ios, background, sms

I want to send SMS functionality in background without open popup for SMS.

To solve this issue I need to make the app send SMS in background. There used to be CTMessage Center in CoreTelephony Framework for such cases before. But now it is not available. Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: there is no public API to send a SMS without the user interaction

Comment: `CTMessageCenter` will only work on jailbroke devices and Apple can change the working of this class without prior warnings. If you want an AppStore app then you will need to provide your own SMS api (via web services). You will not be able to send a SMS via the system.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this if you want to publish the app to the App Store. You can always work with private API but I highly doubt a header dump will reveal anything on sending text in the background. This is for privacy concerns and Apple will reject apps that use private API.

If you are willing to pay: [this](https://www.twilio.com/sms) or [this](https://www.eztexting.com/sms-services) (note I am not affiliated, these are just nice ways to solve your problem).

Comment: How has Apple not gotten sued for monopolization of their services?

Comment: @KennyWorden There's no monopolisation. Apple doesn't offer SMS services and its a respect to privacy to disallow apps to send SMS without user interaction. You can easily switch to android and other mobile OSes, apple isn't the sole player in the market.